# Setting initial Pattern in FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog for files without extension

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to filter only files without extensions in `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog`.
I used the code below.

```
FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog dia = new FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog(
                                       getShell(), true, ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(), IResource.FILE);
dia.setInitialPattern("?"); //Which Pattern I need to set here?
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter in `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` just runs the name match part of the pattern if there is no extension, so I can't see a way to get this.

It looks like you could create a subclass of `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` and override the `createFilter` method and provide your own filter to do what you want.